# In RoR, how do I initialize fields in my model based on a field in my model that has no underlying database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, initialization, rails-activerecord

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have an attribute in my model that doesn’t have a database field underneath it

```
  attr_accessor :division
```

This gets initialized when I create a new object.

```
  my_object = MyObject.new(:name => name,
                         :age => get_age(data_hash),
                         :overall_rank => overall_rank,
                         :city => city,
                         :state => state,
                         :country => country,
                         :age_group_rank => age_group_rank,
                         :gender_rank => gender_rank,
                         :division => division)
```

What I would like is when this field gets set (if it is not nil), for two other fields that do have mappings in the database to get set.  The other fields would be substrings of the “division” field.  Where do I put that logic?

Comment: Have you looked at Active Record callbacks? eg `after_initialization` ? you could write a callback that checks the value of that field and sets the other two, at that stage.

Comment: Would I define a method called "after_initialization" in my model?  I'm not seeing that in the Rails documentation.

Comment: Here's the rails guide on using callbacks: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html
Worth a read - they're quite useful :)

Comment: here's the bit specifically about `after_initialize` (but it's still worth reading through the whole thing so you fully understand what you're doing...)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find

Comment: @TarynEast The problem is that `after_initialize` (or the other hooks) won't run when you say `o.division = ...`, they only run when they are specifically triggered through the lifecycle methods (`new`, `create`, `save`, ...).

Comment: The example code uses `new` - which means it should run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably drop the `attr_accessor :division` and do it by hand with:

```
def division=(d)
  # Break up `d` as needed and assign the parts to the
  # desired real attributes.
end

def division
  # Combine the broken out attributes as needed and
  # return the combined string.
end
```

With those two methods in place, the following will all call `division=`:

```
MyObject.new(:division => '...')
MyObject.create(:division => '...')
o = MyObject.find(...); o.update(:division => '...')
o = MyObject.find(...); o.division = '...'
```

so the `division` and the broken out attributes will always agree with each other.

If you try to use one of the lifecycle hooks (such as `after_initialize`) then things can get out of sync. Suppose `division` has the form `'a.b'` and the broken out attributes are `a` and `b` and suppose that you're using one of the ActiveRecord hooks to break up `division`. Then saying:

```
o.division = 'x.y'
```

should give you `o.a == 'x'` but it won't because the hook won't have executed yet. Similarly, if you start with `o.division == 'a.b'` then

```
o.a = 'x'
```

won't give you `o.division == 'x.b'` so the attributes will have fallen out of sync again.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of options here
You can add it in your controller as follows

```
def create
  if params[:example][:division]
    # Set those params here
  end 
end
```

Or you can use before_save In your model

```
before_save :do_something

def do_something
  if division
    # Here!
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you need to do "if division != nil"?  Couldn't you just do "if division" instead?

Comment: Yea sure . . . . . . . . . .